# SQL code in Access says error in FROM clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT
    p.Name,
    p.Age,
    MAX(COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) / (COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) + COUNT(m.lossTeam_ID)))
FROM Players AS p
INNER JOIN Teams AS t
    ON t.ID = p.Team_ID
INNER JOIN Matches AS m
    ON m.Team_ID = t.ID
GROUP BY
    p.Name,
    p.Age;
```

Comment: Please add some more information about your question. The layout of the tables would be helpful, as would some sample data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: I see multiple problems with your query.  What is the meaning behind using `MAX` there?  It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Sample data , desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    p.Name,
    p.Age,
    COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) / (COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) + COUNT(m.lossTeam_ID))
FROM (Players AS p
INNER JOIN Teams AS t
    ON t.ID = p.Team_ID)
INNER JOIN Matches AS m
    ON m.Team_ID = t.ID
GROUP BY
    p.Name,
    p.Age
ORDER BY
    COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) / (COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) + COUNT(m.lossTeam_ID)) DESC;
```

This fixes the syntax problem with your joins.  It also interprets the `MAX` as meaning that you want the record with the maximum ratio of counts.  In this case, we can use `TOP 1` along with `ORDER BY` to identify this max record.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access requires strange parentheses when you have more than one `join`.  In addition, `MAX(COUNT(m.winTeam_ID))` doesn't make sense.  I don't know what you are trying to calculate in the `SELECT`.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Age,
       COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) / (COUNT(m.winTeam_ID) + COUNT(m.lossTeam_ID)))
FROM (Players AS p INNER JOIN
      Teams AS t
      ON t.ID = p.Team_ID
     ) INNER JOIN
     Matches AS m
     ON m.Team_ID = t.ID
GROUP BY p.Name, p.Age;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Matches` table shouldn't have a `Team_ID` And instead you have `winTeam_ID` and `lossTeam_ID`!
And also you want to query players of a team with - something like - the best win-rate.

If so, Use a query like this - tested on SQL Server only -:

```
select 
    p.Age, p.Name, ts.rate
from 
    Players p
join
    (select top(1) -- sub-query will return just first record
        t.ID
        , sum(case when (t.ID = winTeam_ID) then 1 else 0 end) as wins
        , sum(case when (t.ID = lossTeam_ID) then 1 else 0 end) as losses
        , sum(case when (t.ID = winTeam_ID) then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / 
          (sum(case when (t.ID = winTeam_ID) then 1.0 else 0.0 end) + sum(case when (t.ID = lossTeam_ID) then 1.0 else 0.0 end)) as rate
    from Teams as t
    left join Matches as m
      on t.ID = m.winTeam_ID
      or t.ID = lossTeam_ID
    group by t.ID 
    order by rate desc       -- This will make max rate as first
    ) as ts                  -- Team stats calculated in this sub-query
  on p.Team_ID = ts.ID;
```